# Line Items are delivering but not appearing on site

Tags: double-click, google-dfp

I'm running an HTML5 file on Google ads manager however it does not appear on the website. Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue? It says that its delivering on ads manager

Comment: Can you provide some code samples or at the very least the website where the adverts are being served?

Comment: Do you see any impressions recorded on your Ad Manager interface ? If yes, sounds like your creative might have a trouble rendering properly. If no, it could mean your targeting or even your integration is not proper. Need more details to help you.